# Adding multiple items to a list in flutter

Tags: list, flutter, dart

I'm new to coding in general and I am working in flutter right now. I've successfully been able to add single string objects into a list but I'm having issues adding an object with multiple strings into a list. I'd love some guidance if anyone's able to help!

This is my model

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';

@JsonSerializable(anyMap: true, explicitToJson: true)
class Product {
  String productName;
  String productDescription;

  Product(this.productName, this.productDescription);

  factory Product.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
    _$ProductFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$ProductToJson(this);
}

Product _$ProductFromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
  return Product(
    json['product name'] as String,
    json['product description'] as String,
  );
}

Map<String, dynamic> _$ProductToJson(Product instance) => <String, dynamic>{
      'product name': instance.productName,
      'product description': instance.productDescription,
    };

//trying to add Product strings into products
class UserData {
  ...
  final List<dynamic> accommodations; //successfully able to add single strings to list
  final List<dynamic> products; //unable to add multiple string objects to this list
  ...

  UserData(
      {...
      this.accommodations,
      this.products
      ...}
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {"products": this.products};
}
```

Here is the database function to connect it to firestore

```
  Future addProduct(List products) async {
    Map<String, dynamic> productMap = {
      'products': products.map((product) => products.toList())
    };
    await userCollection.doc(uid).update(productMap);
  }
```

The await, which I've edited multiple times, either throws an error "ArgumentError (Invalid argument: Instance of 'Product')" OR "_TypeError (type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<dynamic, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, Object>')"

Finally, here is the onPressed event which I'm trying to use to insert the two string values into the products list.

```
String _currentProductName;
String _currentProductDescription;
```

these are hooked up to textformfields

```
onChanged: (val) {
 setState(() => _currentProductName = val);
},
onChanged: (val) {
 setState(() => _currentProductDescription = val);
},
```

and the onPressed which I've also tried changing multiple times

```
RaisedButton(onPressed: () async {
 userData.products.add(Product(
  _currentProductName,
  _currentProductDescription));
 await DatabaseService(uid: user.uid).addProduct(userData.products);
}),
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Firestore only accept maps for updates so what you want is to map your product to it's map representation. I'm on mobile, so spare with me for the formatting, but that would look something like this

products.map((p) => p.toMap()).toList()